# Writing summation without knowing if a random variable is discrete or continuous

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, inequality, summation, random-variables

I was trying to proof an exercise problem and stumbled into this dilemma.
The problem is that as follows:
We have some r.v. with unknown distribution $Y_1,...,Y_n$ and Rademacher r.v. $\epsilon_1,...,\epsilon_n$ 
I tried to bound
$$P(\frac{\sum Y_i \epsilon_i}{(\sum Y_i^2)^{1/2}} > \sqrt{2t})<e^{-t}$$
by setting $A_i=\frac{Y_i}{(\sum Y_i^2)^{1/2}}$ 
we can rewrite the formula as $P(\sum A_i \epsilon_i > \sqrt{2t})$
and since $\sum A_i = 1$ I can bound the probability by conditioning on $A_i$ and use Hoeffding Inequality.
Something like

$$P(\sum A_i \epsilon_i > \sqrt{2t}) = \sum? \int?\ P(\sum a_i \epsilon_i > \sqrt{2t}\ |\ A_i = a_i\ for\ all \ i)P(A_i = a_i\ for\ all \ i)$$

The first term can be bounded by Hoeffding and taken out of the formula, leaving the second term summed to 1.
Hence the probability is bounded by $e^{-t}$.
But the problem is that I know nothing about $Y_i$. I don't know how to write the summation there.
Is there any way rigorous way to write that?